# What error should I return when a COM object has been deleted but is being attempted to be referenced?

Tags: com

I have extended an API in C++ written on a legacy framework that is used via `JavaScript`/`VB`.  There is an object that can create from another object.  However, the coder can hold on to that object (it's exposed) and do operations on it.  Also, the object can be deleted.  Because of that last part, I need to keep the object around, even when it is deleted in case the developer tries to reference through that object, and if they attempt to do so, return an error (`HRESULT`), otherwise, it could cause a crash.

What is the best common `HRESULT` that I should use?  I can't seem to find one that matches what I want.

The only one that I found the `winerr.h` file that might be relivant is  `ERROR_FLT_DELETING_OBJECT`, but I don't think it is meant for that.

## EDIT

Perhaps I should not use the word `delete`  and replace it with instead `detach`.  The object is to be `detached` from the main object, but is still lives on till the gc cleans up.  However, if the user were to attempt to use this `detached` object, I want them to wake up to the fact that they have already detached it and that they shouldn't be playing with it any more.

## EXAMPLE

```js
var newObj = container.create_newObject();
newObj.doStuff();
container.doStuffWithNewObject(newObject);
container.RemoveObject(newObj);
newObj.doStuff();  // ERROR - see, still have reference and attempting to do stuff.
container.doStuffWithNewObject(newObject); // ERROR
```

Comment: It is a **bug**.  COM objects are reference-counted so this is never possible.   It is not the client code that deletes the object, it is your code.  When Release() counts down to 0 then you must destroy it.  Which includes having to reset a pointer you keep internally from one object to another.  So at no point could you even detect this mishap.  It is not entirely impossible for client code to fumble the AddRef/Release calls, but you have little to fear from V8.

Comment: @HansPassant yes, you're right that it shouldn't crash the platform. That is what I want to avoid. However, if/when the application developer tries to use the object, I want there to be something to let the user know that they did something stupid. BTW, what is meant by V8?

Comment: There isn't any way for him to use the object without having a valid interface reference.  On which AddRef() was called.  This is done by the language runtime in the case of JavaScript and VB (or V8), it doesn't fumble these calls.  So telling him he did something "stupid" would be excessively misleading, nothing he did wrong and nothing he can do about it.  The only one that could get this wrong is you.

Comment: @HansPassant, I disagree. Trying to use an object that is not attached to anything doesn't harm anything but it is still stupid.  Also, attempting to do something with the object might be not intentional (well, it shouldn't be, as for it to work, it needs to reference that which it is attached to), so the developer should be informed about this, as it would be a **bug**.

Comment: Actually try to induce this bug, the only way to see the light.  There is a standard HRESULT error code for bad pointers, E_POINTER.  The language runtime turns it into an exception.

Comment: @HansPassant, THAT'S what I'm looking for.  THANK YOU!